# Точки после кавычек и скобок

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, вставная-конструкция

**Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку – «кто был прав?»**

Нужна ли точка после закрывающей кавычки? Ведь здесь и не косвенная и не прямая речь. (Совсем запутался).
Кстати, как правильно: ***(Совсем запутался).*** или ***(Совсем запутался.)***?
То есть где точка? Внутри скобок или вне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точка всегда ставится **после** закрывающих кавычек, но не перед ними.
Многоточие, вопросительный и восклицательный знак ставятся **перед** закрывающими кавычками.
Точка ставится и в том случае, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, а выступает как часть придаточного (даже если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак).
[**Как оформлять цитаты?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76)

**Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку – «кто был прав?».**

1. Если вставка является самостоятельным предложением, то точка ставится внутри скобок (обратите внимание – Вы пропустили запятую):
   **Ведь здесь и не косвенная, и не прямая речь. (Совсем запутался.)**
2. Если вставка входит в предложение, то внутри скобок точка не ставится; слова в скобках начинаются со строчной буквы:
   **Ведь здесь и не косвенная, и не прямая речь (совсем запутался).**

Некоторые примеры (К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоём):

- — Последний кусочек? — (Кортни большим пальцем показала вниз — маленький император в Колизее. **Зевнула.)** — Тогда в постель, — сказала Трейси, изо всех сил делая вид, будто знает, что делает.
- Вряд ли стоило говорить такое человеку, который потерял внука, у которого дочь — овощ. («В стабильном вегетативном состоянии», — поправляла **Барбара.)**

Answer (score 2):

**Интересно, о чем это?** Ведь чтобы редактировать текст, **нужно понимать его смысл.**

Это конкретная жизненная ситуация,  это спор о смысле жизни?  И откуда здесь дословное высказывание, почему его надо заключать в кавычки?

Пока ясности нет и нет контекста, всё это может выглядеть следующим образом (СПП с придаточным изъяснительным):

**Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку, кто (из них) был прав.**

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт точки внутри скобок - сомневаюсь, что в Вашем случае это применимо и что этот знак в употреблении отличается от точки после кавычек.

Что касаетчя кавычек, то знаки препинания определённо ставятся только после них.

Что касается цитирования, то в Вашем примере, полагаю, речь всё же о [косвенном пересказе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), для передачи которого средствами русского языка достаточно запятой без кавычек:

***Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку, кто же был прав.***

Answer (score 1):

По какому-то дурацкому правилу, которое дружно игнорируют все редакции ("сто редакторов с корректором, кинохроника с прожектором"), **полагается ставить точку после закрывающих кавычек**,

даже если им предшествует знак вопроса или восклицания,

**если предложение повествовательное**.

Когда интонация предложения и знак перед кавычками совпадают, его не дублируют.

Но, повторю, педагог, может, и похвалит за знание правила, а редактор с корректором забракуют!

Кстати, в Вашем примере неясна етая самая интонация; возможен такой вариант:

*Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку – «кто был прав»?* -

то есть к чертям вопрошание в кавычках - выносим его за (вопрос о том, когда именно - в посмерии? - мы узнаем кто).

А возможен такой - с утверждением, и всё становится повествовательным:

*Только в посмертии будут даны объяснения человеку – «кто был прав».*

---

Со скобками и точкой в них или вне - совсем простенько.

Самостоятельное предложение - хоть бы из одного слова состоящее - имеет точку вовнутрях, т. е. конструкцию можно изъять из контекста, никакого мусора (в виде точки) за собой не оставляя.